# what is "Segmentation fault" explanation , Google Assistant on Raspberry pi

Tags: segmentation-fault, google-assistant-sdk

why this is happened nobody  answered that.
i followed instruction on [google page](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/run-sample).
on step : "Run the Sample Code" when the code run, the issue happened and lack of explanation. only says "Segmentation fault".
Problem on this: "googlesamples-assistant-hotword...."
run on this without problem: "googlesamples-assistant-demo...."
So what happining, what is the real problem about this "segmentation fault" thing anobody can explain please

Comment: If you go to your favorite search engine and enter the search terms `what is a segmentation fault` you should be able to get quite a few explanations about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

Comment: no.. if i can find it i dont have to ask here. i search it 2 weeks. i dont understand the problem of Google Assistant segmentation fault. i solved it but i Just wanna understand real thing about the problem. so if u know please answer or dont be smart... everybody know here searching...